# php manipulate strings in foreach loop

Tags: php, string, foreach

I would like to loop through an array with .png filenames, get the image orientation, prepend 'a' for landscape 'b' for portrait so i have them sorted for gallery output.

How can I edit the strings, while looping through the array $images ?

Thank you.

```
foreach ($images as $img) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/img" . $img);
    if ($width > $height) {
        // how to prepend 'a' to $img?
    }
    else {
       // how to prepend 'b' to $img?
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify is `$img` the string what you want to append to?

Comment: @RossWilson yes, i changed the question to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have either have to pass the value by reference or use something like array map.

Pass by reference is simply adding an `&` before the iteration value:

```
foreach ($images as &$img) {

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/img" . $img);

    $img = (($width > $height) ? 'a' : 'b') . $img;
}
```

Using `array_map`

```
$images = array_map(function ($img) {

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/img" . $img);

    $img = (($width > $height) ? 'a' : 'b') . $img;

    return $img;

}, $images);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the reference method works perfectly, but of course i need to prepend not append, my bad. Sorry to bother you again and thanks for your good answer

Comment: @Gregor can you edit you post to say prepend instead of append just so people don't get confused if they see this. :)

Comment: thanks for your patience and teaching my some php short forms :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($images as $img) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/img" . $img);
    if ($width > $height) {
        $actual_string .= 'a';
    }
    else {
        $actual_string .= 'b';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

this is what you may be looking for

```
foreach ($images as $key => $img) {
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/img" . $img);
  if ($width > $height) {
    $images[$key] = 'a'.$images[$key];
  }
  else {
    $images[$key] = 'b'.$images[$key];
  }
}
```